# Impact and the risk of set the param sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid to 0 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to generate and PDF using an HTML page using electron-pdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pdf) . The pdf is generated but it's vague and not the exact html rendered when opened with a browser. I'm getting this warning too . MESA-"INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0 " . Is that error relates to this misbehavior of the library ?  and what are the consequences and risks involved if I set the  dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid param to 0 . I have attached the html below and the snap shot of the generated pdf .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <style>
        /* Reset some default styles for cross-browser consistency */
        body, h1, p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* Apply some basic styling */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            color: #333;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        nav {
            background-color: #444;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        nav li {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        section {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #444;
            color: #fff;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        footer {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Your Website</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <h2>Welcome to Your Website</h2>
        <p>This is a basic HTML template with some simple CSS styling.</p>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                    <th>Column 5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Add more rows here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <h2>Savings and Accruals</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column A</th>
                    <th>Column B</th>
                    <th>Column C</th>
                    <th>Column D</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data AA</td>
                    <td>Data AB</td>
                    <td>Data AC</td>
                    <td>Data AD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data BA</td>
                    <td>Data BB</td>
                    <td>Data BC</td>
                    <td>Data BD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data CA</td>
                    <td>Data CB</td>
                    <td>Data CC</td>
                    <td>Data CD</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data DA</td>
                    <td>Data DB</td>
                    <td>Data DC</td>
                    <td>Data DD</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
    <footer>
        &copy; 2023 Your Website
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]